# How to remove everything after the 2nd underscore but keep the other columns?

Tags: awk, sed, command-line

my file.txt looks like this

```
variant_id pval_nominal
1_752721_A_G_b37 2.23485e-05
1_900397_C_T_b37 3.04603e-05
1_928297_G_A_b37 2.12455e-05
```

I am trying to remove everything after the 2nd underscore in the first column so that it looks like this:

```
variant_id pval_nominal
1_752721 2.23485e-05
1_900397 3.04603e-05
1_928297 2.12455e-05
```

The reason why I ask everything after the 2nd underscore in the first column to be removes is that instances in the first column can look like this: 1_1025672_GCA_G_b37

I was trying to use this command:

```
 awk -F _ '{print $1 (NF>1? FS $2 : "")}'  file.txt > file2.txt
```

but file2.txt looks like this:

```
variant_id pval
1_752721
1_900397
1_928297
```

How to run this command so that 2nd column is returned as well?

Thanks

Comment: (1) Your sample data follow a very rigid pattern.  Each line has two “words”, separated by a single space.  The first word is always `1_`, six digits, `_`, a capital letter, another `_`, another capital letter, and `_b37`.  The second word is always a non-zero digit, a **`.`**, five digits, and ``e-05``.  Do all the lines in your real data follow that pattern?  Why do you say “keep the other columns” when there’s always only one other column?  Please say what your data look like, and what features answerers are allowed to assume. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You say ‘‘remove everything after the 2nd underscore (in the first column)’’, but you mean ‘‘remove the 2nd underscore and everything after it’’. Please be precise.

Comment: Hi Scott, this is just part of the file, the pattern is not always the same. So the first column has sometimes instances like this: 1_1025672_GCA_G_b37 . That is why I thought the safest would be just to remove everything after that 2nd underscore in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed 's/_[A-Z].* / /g' file

variant_id pval_nominal
1_752721 2.23485e-05
1_900397 3.04603e-05
1_928297 2.12455e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the main field separator as it is and use *awk*'s *split()* function on the first field.

```
$ awk <data '{ split($1,f1,/_/) ; printf("%s_%s %s\n",f1[1],f1[2],$2) }'
```